# ClassNotFoundException when execute WSO2 Sample 100 in WSO2-ESB 4.5.0

Tags: wso2-esb

I am testing WSO2 sample 100 (a WS-Security sample): http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.3/docs/samples/qos_mediation_samples.html, and deployed SecureStockQuoteService.aar to WSO2-AS.

But WSO2-AS throws "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: samples.userguide.PWCallback" when I run this sample (shell>> ant stockquote -Dtrpurl=http://localhost:8280/).

Should I deploy the samples.userguide.PWCallback API to WSO2-AS, and how to do?

---

1. Recover JCE JARs 1.5 to JDK home if you are using JDK 1.6+
2. Build & Deploy SecureStockQuoteService.aar to AS server
3. Run client by ant, and then AS throws exception:

   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: samples.userguide.PWCallback

---

I tried to run sample with axis2 server by this command: ...esb\samples\axis2Server>axis2server.bat. And I got these messages:

```
Unable to locate a Wrapper executable using any of the following names:
  ...\axis2..\..\bin\native\wrapper-windows-x86-32.exe
  ...\axis2..\..\bin\native\wrapper-windows-x86-64.exe
```

How to fix this error??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to deploy the Sample service in AS you need to deploy all the other dependencies as well. If not you can [simply start the axis2server](http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.3/docs/samples_setup_guide.html#Starting) provided and run the sample.

Comment: I tried to run sample with axis2 server by this command: ...esb\samples\axis2Server>axis2server.bat. And then I got this message: "Unable to locate a Wrapper executable using any of the following names". How to fix this error??

Comment: Have you done any additional steps to the servers ? I was able to start the server without any issue with a fresh 4.5.0 ESB pack

Comment: I am testing usernameToken WS-Security proxy, now. Do you know How to configu a SOAP WS-Security header inside a WSO2 ESB proxy by header mediator?